# Is it possible for Visual Studio to automatically create session variables when building my app

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm developing on my local machine using the built in web server that ships with VS2010. I'm working in the user account area, and it's becoming pretty tedious to relogin with my test account.

At the same time it's also tedious to have to comment/uncomment code when I decide to publish the site to my live server. Is there a way to make Visual Studio create some session variables automatically for me when I build the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can tell you not to comment/uncomment code for make the release but use a DEBUG define

On your development web.config define the DEBUG

```
<compiler compilerOptions="/D:DEBUG" ... >
```

and use as you know.

```
#if DEBUG
.... debugged code....
#else
.... release code....
#endif
```

Now about the session variables, **they are connected with session cookies, so if you close the web server, or the browser this cookies gone**, and you can not do nothing about it.

Avoid to close this 2, while you make your development and you do not need to automatic create session variables.